# TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /api/posts/1

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

In my next.js 13 app, I'm trying to fetch each blog data from local MySQL database, so in `src/blog/[id]/page.js` I have this component:

```
const BlogPost = async ({ params }) => {
     const data = await getData(params.id);


async function getData(id) {
    const res = await fetch(`/api/posts/${id}`, 
    {next: {
      revalidate: 10
    }})
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
    }
    return res.json()
  }
```

Where data is fetched in `src/app/api/posts/[id]/route.js` :

```
export const GET = async (request, {params}) => {   
    const {id} = params 
    console.log('id to fetch is:', id)
   const post = await query({
    query:'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `id` = ?',
    values:[id],
   })

   console.log('post is :', post)
    return NextResponse.json(post);

  }
```

But the component does not reach this route above and I get this error instead:

> error TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /posts/1

The strange thing is that I don't have any issues fetching `/api/posts` in `Blog` component.

I'm wondering what is wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: It should be `fetch("/api/posts/1")` right? and not "/posts/1"?

Comment: @Shri Hari That's right. but it does not fetch `/api/posts/1`

Comment: You have given `await fetch('/posts/${id}')` ? You should give `await fetch('/api/posts/${id}')`

Comment: Right, I fixed that but still get `- error TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /api/posts/1`

Answer (score 0):

After having a closer look, I found the essential error is

```
- error TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'params' as it is undefined.
```

So adding `request to the GET function solved the problem:

```
export const GET = async (request, {params}) => {   
   const {id} = params 
   const post = await query({
   query:'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `id` = ?',
    values:[id],
   })

   return NextResponse.json(post);

  }
```